# How to use the Adobe Source Code Pro font?

Tags: software-installation, fonts

Adobe released an open source font family called "Source Code Pro" (download [here](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-code-pro/releases), Slashdot article [here](http://news.slashdot.org/story/12/09/25/2110200/adobe-releases-new-openly-licensed-coding-font)). How do I install it?

Comment: So many people coming to this question, and not a single one of us has taken the time to just [add a `fonts-source-code-pro`](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=736681) package to Debian...

Answer (score 169, accepted):

1. Download the archive from [the Source Code Pro homepage](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-code-pro/). You can do it also using `wget`: Open a terminal (ctrl-alt-t or press the win key and type "terminal") and type

   ```
   wget https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-code-pro/archive/2.030R-ro/1.050R-it.zip
   ```
2. Unzip the archive (you can use Nautilus for that, or use the following command).

   ```
   unzip 1.050R-it.zip
   ```
3. Locate and ensure your fonts folder exist in your home directory, often in ~/.local/share/fonts folder (either go to home in Nautilus and create a new folder, or type the following from the terminal)

   ```
   fontpath="${XDG_DATA_HOME:-$HOME/.local/share}"/fonts

   mkdir -p $fontpath
   ```

If you already have that directory, don't worry.

4. Move the Open Type fonts (*.otf) to the newly created .fonts directory. In command line, that would be

   ```
   cp source-code-pro-*-it/OTF/*.otf $fontpath
   ```
5. If you haven't done it yet, open a terminal, and type

   ```
   fc-cache -f -v
   ```

Your font is now ready to use and the applications should be able to see it.

All in one script for those who simply want to copy/paste the answer

```
#!/bin/bash
set  -euo pipefail
I1FS=$'\n\t'
mkdir -p /tmp/adodefont
cd /tmp/adodefont
wget -q --show-progress -O source-code-pro.zip https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-code-pro/archive/2.030R-ro/1.050R-it.zip
unzip -q source-code-pro.zip -d source-code-pro
fontpath="${XDG_DATA_HOME:-$HOME/.local/share}"/fonts
mkdir -p $fontpath
cp -v source-code-pro/*/OTF/*.otf $fontpath
fc-cache -f
rm -rf source-code-pro{,.zip}
```

If you want to install system wide instead of per user, copy the files to `/usr/local/share/fonts/` instead of `~/.local/share/fonts/`.

Comment: This doesn't let me use this font on Terminal. What should I do to apply this font on the Terminal?

Comment: @SSchneid I've seen your edit proposal and rejected it. Please, either correct the whole answer and replace the dead links with working ones or submit a new answer.

Answer (score 55):

In order to install Source Code Pro, you can:

1. Go to [Google Fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts)
2. Type `source code` in the search box (the only match should be Source Code Pro)
3. Click "Add to collection"
4. Click on the text sample (this should present all the font styles)
5. Tick all the check boxes
6. Click the download icon (a down arrow on the top right) and download as Zip file

Now you just need to decompress the Zip file into your `~/.fonts` folder:

```
mkdir -p ~/.fonts/Source_Code_Pro
unzip Source_Code_Pro.zip  -d ~/.fonts/Source_Code_Pro
```

You may need to run

```
fc-cache -f
```

to make the fonts available (no need to log out).

Comment: This is probably the answer that will age the best.

Comment: This one was the first method to work for me. The other ones I tried either did nothing, or resulted in empty squares.

Comment: If you don't want to clutter your home directory, you can use `~/.local/share/fonts` instead of `~/.fonts`

Answer (score 17):

Thanks for the answer, just a modified script to get the latest file

```
#!/bin/bash
FONT_NAME="SourceCodePro"
URL="https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-code-pro/archive/1.017R.zip"

mkdir /tmp/adodefont
cd /tmp/adodefont
wget ${URL} -O ${FONT_NAME}.zip
unzip -o -j ${FONT_NAME}.zip
mkdir -p ~/.fonts
cp *.otf ~/.fonts
fc-cache -f -v
```

Answer (score 8):

My answer is similar to the others just updating the URL'S as it seems those are removed. Source code pro's new home seems to be on github. [Source code pro on github.](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-code-pro)

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir /tmp/adodefont
cd /tmp/adodefont
wget https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-code-pro/archive/1.017R.zip
unzip 1.017R.zip 
mkdir -p ~/.fonts
cp source-code-pro-1.017R/OTF/*.otf ~/.fonts/
fc-cache -f -v
```

Answer (score 7):

```
sudo wget --content-disposition -P /usr/share/fonts/opentype/source-code-pro https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-code-pro/blob/29fdb884c6e9dc2a312f4a5e2bb3b2dad2350777/OTF/SourceCodePro-{Black,BlackIt,Bold,BoldIt,ExtraLight,ExtraLightIt,It,Light,LightIt,Medium,MediumIt,Regular,Semibold,SemiboldIt}.otf?raw=true
```

That will install the [latest release](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-code-pro/releases/tag/2.038R-ro%2F1.058R-it%2F1.018R-VAR) of the font (as I'm writing this in June 2021, released January 2021).

Comment: For anyone else coming here in late 2021, this is the answer you want to use. It's a single line you can copy and paste into the terminal. There's no longer any need for unzipping and creating directories. The other answers are outdated, and though it's not possible, they should be removed.

Comment: This doesn't work in ZSH, use Bash to run this command, works perfectly in Bash.

Comment: It would be nice to explain parameter(s) and what it does.  It would also be beneficial to know how did you get the `29fdb884c6e9dc2a312f4a5e2bb3b2dad2350777` which probably is unique for this 2021 latest version.

Answer (score 3):

There is also a working [third-party debian package](https://github.com/hainp/source-code-pro-deb) on github.

To install:

```
git clone https://github.com/hainp/source-code-pro-deb 
cd source-code-pro-deb
sudo apt-get install debhelper
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -b -uc -us
sudo dpkg -i ../fonts-source-code-pro_1.017_all.deb
```

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what the OP is asking for, but this might be easier.

You can install the [powerline fonts](https://github.com/powerline/fonts) which include slightly modified versions of a bunch of mono fonts which work with powerline for the prompt and Vim with the vim-airline plugin. It kind of gives you an 'awesome' list of source code mono fonts to try out, including "Source Code Pro". To install all the fonts:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/powerline/fonts.git --depth=1
$ cd fonts
$ ./install.sh
```

Comment: If you install it this way, the font is called `Source Code Pro for Powerline`

Comment: The problem with this repository is that the fonts are not updated.  `Source Code Pro` has 2021 update, but the the font is 5 years old here.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a [GitHub post](https://gist.github.com/lucasdavila/3875946), this script worked for me. I had to modify the folder names to get it to work.

```bash
version=1.050

echo "\n* Downloading version $version of source code pro font"
rm -f SourceCodePro_FontsOnly-$version.zip
rm -rf SourceCodePro_FontsOnly-$version
font_folder=source-code-pro-2.030R-ro-${version}R-it
zip_file=${version}R-it.zip
wget https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-code-pro/archive/2.030R-ro/$zip_file

echo "\n* Unziping package"
unzip $zip_file
mkdir -p ~/.fonts

echo "\n* Copying fonts to ~/fonts"
cp $font_folder/OTF/*.otf ~/.fonts/

echo "\n* Updating font cache"
sudo fc-cache -f -v

echo "\n* Looking for 'Source Code Pro' in installed fonts"
fc-list | grep "Source Code Pro"

echo "\n* Now, you can use the 'Source Code Pro' fonts, ** for sublime text ** just add the lines bellow to 'Preferences > Settings':"
echo '\n  "font_face": "Source Code Pro",'
echo '  "font_size": 10'

echo "\n* Finished :)\n"
```