# Adobe Source Code Pro has two extensions?

Tags: fonts

I found a thread that explained how to install the Adobe Source Code Pro font here: [How to use the new Adobe Source Code Pro font?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193072/how-to-use-the-new-adobe-source-code-pro-font)

I followed the instructions, logged out and logged back in, opened LibreOFfice Writer, and the font still wasn't available.

One thing I noticed that I don't understand is that the TTF and OTF fonts have `.woff` extensions. So the extensions are `.otf.woff` and `.ttf.woff`. I don't actually see any naked `.otf` or `.ttf` extensions. Just deleting the `.woff` out of the filename doesn't seem to fix anything.

Am I missing something fundamental? I'm a total Ubuntu newbie. Do I need to drag the entire folder for the ".fonts" folder to recognize it as a family?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to install Source Code Pro, you can:

1. Go to [Google Fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts)
2. Type `source code` in the search box (the only match should be Source Code Pro)
3. Click "Add to collection"
4. Click on the text sample (this should present all the font styles)
5. Tick all the check boxes
6. Click the download icon (a down arrow on the top right) and download as Zip file

Now you just need to decompress the Zip file into your `~/.fonts` folder:

```
mkdir -p ~/.fonts/Source_Code_Pro
unzip Source_Code_Pro.zip  -d ~/.fonts/Source_Code_Pro
```

You may need to run

```
fc-cache -f
```

to make the fonts available (no need to log out).